How can I resolve this error I keep getting with trying to deploy a Microk8s cluster using ansible
I am trying to create a microk8s cluster on GCP VM using Ansible. I want to Create a three node cluster, one master and two workers.
This is the playbook I am using;
---
- name: Ansible playbook to create Microk8s Cluster
  hosts: kubenodes
  become: true

  tasks:

  - name: Update web servers
    apt:
      upgrade: yes
      update_cache: yes

  - name: Install snap package installer
    apt:
      name: snapd
      state: present

  - name: Install Microk8s
    snap:
      name: microk8s
      classic: true

  - name: Add current user to microk8s group
    shell:
      cmd: "sudo usermod -a -G microk8s {{ ansible_user }}"

- hosts: "master"
  become: true
  vars:
    workers_count: "{{ groups.workers | length }}"
  tasks:   

  - name: Create join node command
    shell: /snap/bin/microk8s add-node
    register: join_token
    ignore_errors: true
    loop: "{{ range(1, num_iterations|int + 1 ) | list }}"
    vars:
      num_iterations: "{{ workers_count }}"

  - set_fact:
      microk8s_join_list: "{{ microk8s_join_list | default([]) + ['/snap/bin/' + item.stdout_lines[4]] }}"
      loop: "{{ join_token.results }}"

  - name: Add Cluster dashboard, Ingress and Cert Manager addon
    shell: /snap/bin/microk8s enable community ingress dashboard cert-manager 

  - name: Add Argocd addon
    shell: /snap/bin/microk8s enable argocd
        
  - name: Store dashboard token
    shell: /snap/bin/microk8s kubectl create token default
    register: dashboard_token
    ignore_errors: true

  - name: Save Kubernetes dashboard token
    set_fact:
      dashboard_token: "{{ dashboard_token.stdout }}"
  
  - name: Run command on worker nodes
    shell: "{{ item }}"
    delegate_to: "{{ groups.workers[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
    loop: "{{ microk8s_join_list }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true

This is my inventory
[master]
35.224.xx.xx

[workers]
107.178.xx.xx
35.225.xx.xx

[kubenodes:children]
workers
master

Every task works fine but the last task Run command on worker nodes.
This is the error I am currently getting;
failed: [35.224.xx.xx -> 107.178.xx.xx] (item=/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker) => {"ansible_loop": {"allitems": ["/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker"], "first": true, "index": 1, "index0": 0, "last": false, "length": 2, "nextitem": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker", "revindex": 2, "revindex0": 1}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname inventory_hostname: Name does not resolve", "unreachable": true}

failed: [35.224.xx.xx -> 35.225.xx.xx] (item=/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker) => {"ansible_loop": {"allitems": ["/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker"], "first": false, "index": 2, "index0": 1, "last": true, "length": 2, "previtem": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "revindex": 1, "revindex0": 0}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname inventory_hostname: Name does not resolve", "unreachable": true}

fatal: [35.224.xx.xx -> {{ groups.workers[ansible_loop.index0] }}]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "All items completed", "results": [{"ansible_loop": {"allitems": ["/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker"], "first": true, "index": 1, "index0": 0, "last": false, "length": 2, "nextitem": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker", "revindex": 2, "revindex0": 1}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname inventory_hostname: Name does not resolve", "unreachable": true}, {"ansible_loop": {"allitems": ["/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker"], "first": false, "index": 2, "index0": 1, "last": true, "length": 2, "previtem": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/62733ae8aca2493665dc2fb3c8a7ec2a/04e060b6d262 --worker", "revindex": 1, "revindex0": 0}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "/snap/bin/microk8s join 10.128.0.26:25000/4dbfa58f2a996760ab51e41369d718ef/04e060b6d262 --worker", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname inventory_hostname: Name does not resolve", "unreachable": true}]}

Please note, when modified for just one worker node the playbook works, but for a multi node cluster I get the above error.
I have tried creating a dummy node to hold the join command, I couldnt figure it out. I have also tried using debug to printout groups.workers[ansible_loop.index0] to see if I am getting the workers IP and offcourse to got printed out without any errors, but it doesnt just work for the main task.

I believe delegate_to only works on a single host (and doesn't get reassigned in every loop operation), so it makes sense that you are seeing that error for groups.workers[ansible_loop.index0]:
  - name: Run command on worker nodes
    shell: "{{ item }}"
    delegate_to: "{{ groups.workers[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
    loop: "{{ microk8s_join_list }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true

in essence groups.workers[ansible_loop.index0] when you have all workers would translate to something like 107.178.xx.xx 35.225.xx.xx which is not a resolvable hostname. When you have a single worker it would work because it would resolve to something like 107.178.xx.xx and that's resolvable.
✌️

Thaanks @Rico, your response was helpful,. This was how I solved it
- name: Run command on worker nodes
    shell: "{{ microk8s_join_list[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ groups.workers }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true

